# Spreading out/pulling apart overlapping polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features

There has been a lot of questions and answers on clipping/removing overlapping polygons in QGIS. However, my question is a bit different. Say, I have a mess of many polygons overlapping one another on this map (let's assume it's a fictional map), I would like a mechanism to pull them apart/spread them out so they no longer overlap. Toggle edit is possible but it is manual and requires moving every single polygon. Is there a quicker method?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing your polygons? Does it matter if they become very far apart or do you want them as close as possible without overlapping?

Comment: @BERA it's more of a hypothetical idea just in case, but I guess if it's to be used as a fictional map that's "plausible" then it would be good to get them as close as possible

Comment: To be able to answer it I think you would need to see some real data. I would probably try to use python and move each polygon kind of randomly until it doesnt intersect anyone. Or create a point grid, snap the polygons to the points. But that would make the gaps bigger